# posts_per_page & pagination conflict

Tags: pagination, loop

I have a custom query to display my custom post type. `posts_per_page` set to '5'. In admin post per page set to '10' (settings => Reading => Blog pages show at most 10 posts)
My template lists 5 posts per page. If I have 15 posts it must be shown in 3 pages, **but on third page I get 404 error.**  So my pagination uses the admin settings (10 posts per page). How can I fix it?

```
global $paged;
query_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_type',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'paged' => $paged
    ));

while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    the_title();
endwhile;

next_posts_link('Next');
previous_posts_link('Prev');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pagination is calculated before you get to the template file that runs `query_posts`. The proper way to alter `posts_per_page` conditionally is to use the `pre_get_posts` hook to modify the main query.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I googled a lot and I realized my concept is absolutely wrong. My code above is part of a `taxonomiy-$taxonomiy-$term.php` file which has a main query. `query_posts();` is for altering main query in custom templates. So I delete `query_posts();` and have to modify my main query with a hook, am I right? :) I tried to hook with `pre_get_posts` but couldn't managed. Could you please show me an example? thanks

Comment: Ok, now everithing works great. I deleted the whole `query_posts` from template file, and put a `pre_get_posts` hook into `functions.php` thank you for your help you drove me to the right way. ;)